# Wiring 1 humbucker, 2 singles, 1 tone knob with YKE switch

Tags: electric-guitar, wiring

So I got this cheap used guitar (Invasion brand). It has H+S+S setup, two knobs and a 5-way pickup switch.

Currently it's wired like this:

[image: Current wiring]

As you can see, it's not wired properly (the humbucker is not connected to anything). If possible, it must be connected like shown in the table («Desired coil connection») where «B/2» singnifies a single coil of the humbucker.

That YKE pickup switch works like shown in the table.

| Switch position ↓ / Pole connection → | 2+3 (N) | 1+3 (M) | 7+3 (B?) | 5+4 (?) | 6+4 (?) | Desired coil connection |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | On |  |  | On |  | N |
| 2 | On | On |  | On |  | N + M |
| 3 |  | On |  |  | On | M |
| 4 |  | On | On |  | On | M + B/2 |
| 5 |  |  | On |  |  | B/2 + B/2 |

Now the humbucker has 3 wires coming out of it: red, white and metal. I don't know what are they connected to, I can only suppose the metal one has to be connected to ground. I have measured the resistance between those wires:

| Wire 1 | Wire 2 | R, kOhm |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Red | Metal | 12.6 |
| White | Metal | 6.5 |
| Red | White | 6.5 |

Given this information, how do I connect the humbucker? I suppose pole 6 of the switch must be used somehow.

Comment: What’s the brand and model of the humbucker? There are two possible reasons for three conductor wiring on a humbucker and only one of them is coil tap/split

Comment: The resistance measurements say it’s wired for coil split

Comment: the humbucker "metal" wire is likely to be earth so should connect to a pot body or pin 8 of the switch. The white orphan wire, is that likely to have been once connected to the white humbucker wire?  perhaps this helps https://www.pinterest.com/pin/166703623690869995/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the table is correct, connecting the metal wire to ground, red wire to 7 and white wire to 6 should work.

The resistance measurements tell that there are two parts that are wired between metal-white and white-red. These are the humbucker coils. Modern humbuckers designed to work with any wiring scheme would have separate pair of wires for each coil and one extra wire for ground to allow wiring coils in parallel and for phase reversal, but with this one coil tap is the only option.

When red is connected to 7 and white to 6, position 5 would connect only 7 (both coils in series) to tone circuit. In position 4 the 6+4 connection would short circuit one coil and the other coil would be now between 7 and ground. The 1+3 and 7+3 connections connect the single coil and half humbucker to tone circuit in parallel.

BTW, the picture has neck pickup connected to 1 and middle to 2 and the table has them the other way round. Other strange detail is that 5-4 is connected both for position 1 and 2. If it was just 2 or 2 and 3, it would work for splitting neck humbucker for position 2, but I have no idea what this configuration could be used for.